# dotted lines not displayed

Tags: wine, display-resolution

I am trying to display some graphs and some of the lines are supposed to be dotted.  Only  a small amount of the dots display making the dotted lines virtually impossible to see.  The application runs fine on windows which I don't want to use.  It is only designed for windows so I use it on Ubuntu with Wine with the only problem being that the dotted lines don't show up well.  I already have maximum resolution and cannot find anything else to adjust.

Comment: Graph of what, from which program! I am totally lost!

Comment: I was going to attach a picture but the site doesn't appear to have a way for me to do that.